# sheaf of principal parts and sheaf of jets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry, jet-bundles

Let $(M,\mathcal{O}_M)$ be a complex manifold. Let $\Delta\colon M\to M\times M$ be the diagonal map and 
$\mathcal{I}$ the kernel of $\Delta^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{M\times M}\to \mathcal{O}_M$.
In [this note](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405563v1), the author shows that

> the **sheaf of order $n$ principal parts**
>   $$ 
> \mathcal{P}^{(n)}:=\Delta^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{M\times M}/\mathcal{I}^{n+1} 
> $$ 
>   are isomorphic to  the **sheaf of $n$-jets**
>   $$
> \mathcal{J}et^{(n)}:=(\mathcal{O}_M\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}\mathcal{O}_M)/\mathcal{J}^{n+1},
> $$ 
>   where $\mathcal{J}$ is the kernel of the multiplication $\mathcal{O}_M\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}\mathcal{O}_M\to\mathcal{O}_M$ 
>   and both of them are locally free $\mathcal{O}_M$-modules.

(OK, it requires "if $M$ is smooth", but I think $M$ is smooth being viewed as a complex analytic space.)

**Question 1:** shouldn't $\mathcal{P}^{(n)}$, instead of $\mathcal{J}et^{(n)}$, be called the *sheaf of jets* as the usual notion of Jet bundle is constructed from $\mathcal{P}^{(n)}$?

Then, it follows that 
$$
\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2\cong\mathcal{J}/\mathcal{J}^2.
$$
Here the first corresponds to the cotangent bundle hence is the sheaf of *holomorphic differentials* $\Omega_M^1$, while the later, by a result in commutative algebra seeing for example [in Stack Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00RW), is isomorphic to the sheaf of Kahler differentials $\Omega_{\mathcal{O}_M/\mathbb{C}}^1$.

However, from [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6074/kahler-differentials-and-ordinary-differentials), *Kahler differentials* are very different from *holomorphic differentials*. We only have a surjective homomorphism
$$
\Omega_{\mathcal{O}_M/\mathbb{C}}^1\longrightarrow\Omega_M^1
$$
which is NOT an isomorphism (consider $de^z-e^zdz$ for example). 
In particular, the $\Omega_M^1$ is locally free of rank $\dim(M)$ while $\Omega_{\mathcal{O}_M/\mathbb{C}}^1$ cannot be since the share the same dual module - the module of derivations.

**Question 2:** What's wrong in here?

(My guess: I misunderstand the above statements of isomorphic 
as the product is taken in a different category than the category of complex manifolds.)

Even ignore the isomorphism issue, the statement that $\mathcal{J}et^{(n)}$ is locally free is still strange for me since $\Omega_{\mathcal{O}_M/\mathbb{C}}^1$ is not locally free as mentioned before.

**Question 3:** What's wrong in here?

Comment: Nice question! Regarding question 1, the book *Lie Equations - General Theory, vol. I* by Kumpera and Spencer agrees with your suggestion: on page 53 the authors write $\mathscr J_k:=\Delta^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{X\times X}/\mathcal{I}^{k+1}$ and explicitly refer to $\mathscr J_k$ as the sheaf of $k$-jets on page 54. Regarding questions 2,3, [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/33286/69037) seems to prove the constructions are isomorphic in the category of locally ringed spaces. In particular it seems the smoothness assumption is superfluous (making remark 5.10 in the linked paper suspicious).